# Why is the format specifier for uint8_t and uint16_t the same (%u)?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I only found pretty unrelated questions due to the tons of results searching for `printf()`.

Why does `uint8_t` not specify its own format string but any other type does?

As far as I understand `printf()`, it has to know the length of the supplied parameters to be able to parse the variable argument list.

Since `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` use the same format specifier `%u`, how does `printf()` "know" how many bytes to process? Or is there somehow an implicit cast to `uint16_t` involved when supplying `uint8_t`?

Maybe I am missing something obvious.

Comment: @PaulRoub: That question is actually exactly what my questions motivation was about, thanks. I missed using "integer promotions" as search keyword.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`printf()` is a variadic function. Its optional arguments( and only those ) get promoted according to default argument promotions( 6.5.2.2. p6 ).

Since you are asking for integers, integer promotions are applied in this case, and types you mention get promoted to `int`. ( and not `unsigned int` because C )

If you use `"%u"` in printf(), and pass it an `uint16_t` variable, then the function converts that to an `int`, then to an `unsigned int`( because you asked for it with %u ) and then prints it.

Comment: This promotion also happens for non-variadic functions.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No it does not.

Comment: It also happens for non-prototyped functions, in case that's what Basile's getting at.

Answer (score 37):

Because %u stands for "unsigned", it well may be uint64_t and is architecture dependent. According to `man 3 printf`, you may want to use length modifier to get sought behaviour, i.e. %hu (uint16_t) and %hhu (uint8_t).

Comment: Do you mean %hhu ? I think length modifier is prefixed, not postfixed.

Comment: @Bram: thank you. Fixed.