# GCC interprets uint8_t and uint16_t as signed?

Tags: linux, c++11, gcc

My test code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    const constexpr uint8_t x = 64;
    printf("%u", x);
}
```

Here is how I compiled with GCC 8.2:

```
g++ -Wall test_format.cpp -o test_format -O3 -std=c++17 -Wformat-signedness
```

And here is GCC's output:

```
test_format.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_format.cpp:6:9: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("%u", x);
         ^~~~
```

Tho, if I try to print an `uint32_t`, it has no error/warning.

I wonder why GCC expects `uint8_t` to be signed int.

Thanks.

Comment: this duplicates multiple questions: [Why is the format specifier for uint8_t and uint16_t the same (%u)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26362386/995714)

Answer (score 1):

[Default argument promotions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions) are applied to operands of a variadic function. Under these, an expression of type `unsigned char` is promoted to `int`.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess no way to ask GCC to verify `printf()` completely (including sign here) by ignoring the change of sign due to integral promotion?  I have my own custom `printf()` but it doesn't use variadic function.  However, I would like to leverage GCC's checks.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your question. In what way do you believe the verification is incomplete? The program shown exhibits undefined behavior, by way of passing an `int` where `unsigned int` is expected. The fact that GCC catches this is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ types narrower than int are always promoted to int. See [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/995714)

And inside variadic functions default promotion also applies, which means you can't pass types narrower than int to vararg functions. So `uint8_t` must be printed with `%d`, not `%u`. But anyway you're printing it the wrong way. The correct way is to use `PRIu8`

```
printf("%" PRIu8 "\n", x);
```

- [Format specifiers for uint8_t, uint16_t, ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6993132/995714)
- [printing the uint8_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14358967/995714)
- [Why is the format specifier for uint8_t and uint16_t the same (%u)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26362386/995714)
- [How do I print uint32_t and uint16_t variables value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12120426/995714)

Answer (score 0):

To print a `uint8_t` variable with `printf()`, you should do something like the following:

```
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstdio>

int print_u8(std::uint8_t x) {
  return std::printf("%" PRIu8 "\n", x);
}
```

The `<cinttypes>` header includes printf and scanf format specifiers for all the `<cstdint>` types (and explicitly includes that header) that should be used for maximum portability.

Comment: This is quite interesting.  I just tried `printf(PRIu8)` and it printed `u`.  So the specifier is still `%u`; however, GCC would happily check it even with the integral promotion.

Comment: I wish we could just use `%u` as at the end `"%" PRIu8` gives `%u` anyway.

Comment: sorry for accepted and then unaccepted because I just tried, same warning.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=5747